# When I have android-mode loaded, Emacs will fail to open a file

Tags: android, emacs

The error is:

> Symbol's function definition is void: locate-dominating-file

Android mode can be found [here](https://raw.github.com/remvee/android-mode/master/android-mode.el). I'm using Emacs version 23.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The missing function (locate-dominating-file) is not available for Emacs version below 24. Use [this backported version](https://github.com/technomancy/emacs-starter-kit/blob/master/dominating-file.el) before loading android-mode.

The answer can be found [here](https://github.com/remvee/android-mode/issues/13).